# Discrepancy between edit preview and actual posted question

Tags: bug, editor

The problem in short:

- Markdown in question editor: 12\/6\/1992 (That's 2 slashes `\` followed by `/` not the letter V)
- Editor Preview             : 12\/6\/1992
- Actual output when posted  : 12/6/1992

Detailed explanation:

**There seems to be a discrepancy between the preview shown in the editor and the actual posted question. In the preview window `\` followed by `/` displays both characters as in the following image:**

[image: Edit mode with preview below]

**However, When the question is posted, `\` followed by `/` displays just the second character (`/`) as in the following image:**

[image: Posted question]

Comment: Is my question really that unclear? It's supposed to show that you see one thing when you look at the edit preview but the actual output in the post does not match the preview. I'm willing to explain further if you have queries regarding it, but if you still feel like down-voting / closing, that's your call.

Comment: @AshwinNair Your question should not have involved editing an existing question. If you would simply have said "When asking a question, typing \/ looks like \/ in the preview, but it will look like / in the result" that would have been much clearer.

Comment: I don't know whether to give in to popular (apparently) demand and to maintain the edit Braiam made which is what @NisseEngstrom had done earlier or to rollback. The thing is while you may believe it's clearer, I don't think it really is since it leads to answers like Ultimater 's answer below which is an explanation regarding how to escape special characters using markdown. As stated above, I know how to escape characters. I'm just trying to show that there's a discrepancy between the preview edit and the actual output.

Comment: Especially now, considering the question I'd linked has been edited to use escape markdown.

Comment: "*As stated above, I know how to escape characters.*" Where above is it stated? Are you referring to: "*Even if this is due to some special/escape character*"? When I read that using the word "some", it's an indication to me you have no idea why it's doing what it's doing, thus my explanation. If you understand what's going on, edit the question accordingly if you're aiming for rhetorical.

Comment: @Ultimater...It's not rhetorical..."Even if this is due to some special/escape character" is half the sentence. The other half ending with the question mark ("shouldn't the preview be faithful to what is actually posted?") was my question. But yes, clearly the way I've worded this is confusing. I'm working on making this question clearer. Thanks for your answer.